# Why use VisualGroup?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to understand why use VisualGroup like the one below:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
```

When changing visual state is usually done independent of the VisualGroup argument

Eg.

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(MyButton, "Normal", true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VisualState`s inside a [VisualStateGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstategroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are mutually exclusive. You may be in more than one state at a time, as long as they are in different groups.

From the MSDN documentation:

```
For example, the CheckBox has two VisualStateGroup objects. One contains the 
states, Normal, MouseOver, Pressed, and Disabled. The other contains the states, 
Checked, UnChecked, and Indeterminate. The CheckBox can be in states MouseOver 
and UnChecked at the same time, but it cannot be in the MouseOver and Pressed 
states at the same time.
```